# query to fetch email address based on first_nm and last_nm

Tags: sql, oracle

For each email_addr in MEA, it will check for corresponding email_addr in MIS

```
Input table 1                             
MEA(base)
email_addr
yy@gmail.com
xx@gmail.com
```

```
Input table 2
MIS(lookup)
email_addr      first_nm     last_nm
yy@gmail.com     null         null
yy@gmail.com     null         null 
xx@gmail.com     null         null 
xx@gmail.com     xx11         xx22
xx@gmail.com     xx11         null
xx@gmail.com     null         xx22
```

REQ-
If an email address in MEA is not associated with any names in MIS, then it will fetch email address with null first name and null last name.
If the email address in MEA has at least one match in MIS with a non-null first/last name, then exclude any match for that email address where first name and last name are both null.

```
Expected o/p
email_addr       first_nm     last_nm
yy@gmail.com      null         null 
xx@gmail.com      xx11         xx22
xx@gmail.com      xx11         null
xx@gmail.com      null         xx22
```

so 3 scenarios to select 
null null(if its the only record)
value value 
null  value
value null

please suggest ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a first working solution but probably not the best one :

```
SELECT 
     distinct mis.*
FROM mea
JOIN mis ON mea.email_addr = mis.email_addr
WHERE
     first_nm IS NOT NULL or 
     last_nm IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT
     distinct mis.*
FROM mea
JOIN mis ON mea.email_addr = mis.email_addr
WHERE 
     first_nm IS NULL AND 
     last_nm IS NULL AND 
     mea.email_addr NOT IN
     (
          SELECT 
               DISTINCT mea.email_addr
          FROM mea
          JOIN mis ON mea.email_addr = mis.email_addr
          WHERE 
               first_nm IS NOT NULL or 
               last_nm IS NOT NULL
     );
```

OR

```
SELECT 
distinct mis.*
FROM mea
JOIN mis ON mea.email_addr = mis.email_addr
WHERE (first_nm IS NOT NULL or last_nm IS NOT NULL) or
first_nm IS NULL AND last_nm IS NULL AND mea.email_addr NOT IN
(
  SELECT 
  DISTINCT mea.email_addr
  FROM mea
  JOIN mis ON mea.email_addr = mis.email_addr
  WHERE first_nm IS NOT NULL or last_nm IS NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from mis where first_nm is not null or last_nm is not null
union 
select distinct * from mis A where (
(first_nm is null and last_nm is null) or 
not exists(select * from mea B where A.email=B.email)
)
and email not in  
(select distinct email from  mis where first_nm is not null or last_nm is not null);
```

Output

```
xx@gmail.com    xx11    xx22
xx@gmail.com    xx11    
xx@gmail.com            xx22
yy@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You could query only the table `MIS` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* 
FROM MIS s
WHERE s."first_nm" IS NOT NULL OR s."last_nm" IS NOT NULL
OR NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM MIS
  WHERE "email_addr" = s."email_addr" 
    AND ("first_nm" IS NOT NULL OR "last_nm" IS NOT NULL)
)
```

If you really want to search only the emails that exist in `MEA` then you need a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* 
FROM MEA a INNER JOIN MIS s
ON s."email_addr" = a."email_addr"
WHERE s."first_nm" IS NOT NULL OR s."last_nm" IS NOT NULL
OR NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM MIS
  WHERE "email_addr" = s."email_addr" 
    AND ("first_nm" IS NOT NULL OR "last_nm" IS NOT NULL)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0dda32100f91acd60f67815f246d1f0a).
Results:

```
> email_addr   | first_nm | last_nm
> :----------- | :------- | :------
> yy@gmail.com | null     | null
> xx@gmail.com | xx11     | xx22   
> xx@gmail.com | null     | xx22     
> xx@gmail.com | xx11     | null
```

Answer (score 0):

When we need some data from table1 that is related optionally - in table2 may have no related data - to table2, I usually use *`LEFT JOIN`* that we set table1 as left table and table2 as right table.
Also, When we are talking about querying over null values, I usually think about using *`COALESCE()`*, So I can suggest you to use a query like this:

```
select "MEA"."email_addr", "MIS"."first_nm", "MIS"."last_nm"
from "MEA"
left join "MIS"
   on "MEA"."email_addr" = "MIS"."email_addr" 
   and coalesce("MIS"."first_nm", "MIS"."last_nm", '@AllAreNull') != '@AllAreNull' 
order by "MEA"."email_addr", "MIS"."first_nm", "MIS"."last_nm";
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f65d/10)

> Note: `coalesce()` will return first non-null value of fields from left to right, So I use `'@AllAreNull'` value at right to returned if all are `null`.